# allocating memory for pointer and safely freeing them in c language

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

Although it seems a very basic and repeated question, but I did not find a similar question.

So, I want to create a structure contains holds some pointers.
In initialization, I allocate memory to all of them, but I do not assign new values to them.

here is my structure

```
typedef struct my_special_struct{
struct my_special_struct *ptr1;
struct my_special_struct *ptr2;
int val;
}my_special_struct;
```

and here is the initialization function

```
my_special_struct *create_struct(int value,struct my_special_struct pointer1){
    my_special_struct *ptr;
    ptr = (my_special_struct *)malloc(sizeof(my_special_struct));
    ptr->val = value;
    ptr->ptr1 = (my_special_struct *)malloc(sizeof(my_special_struct));
    ptr->ptr1 = pointer1;
    ptr->ptr2 = (my_special_struct *)malloc(sizeof(my_special_struct));
    ptr->ptr2 = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
```

During the program running, some of these pointers should got some values assigned dynamically.
Some times ptr2 got assigned with my_special_struct, and some times it remains empty.

```
my_special_struct *add_ptr2(struct my_special_struct ptr,struct my_special_struct pointer2){
    ptr->ptr2 = pointer2;
    return ptr;
}
```

At the end of the code, I want to free all the pointers that got assigned, here is the function

```
void delete_struct(struct my_special_struct ptr){
   if (ptr->ptr1 != NULL){
          delete_struct(ptr->ptr1);
      }
   else{
          free(ptr->ptr1);
      }
   if (ptr->ptr2 != NULL){
          delete_struct(ptr->ptr2);
      }
   else{
          free(ptr->ptr2);
      }
   free(ptr);

}
```

> **So, my questions:**
>
> 1- should I assign NULL to ptr2 in the `create_struct` function, or
> just memory allocation is enough?
>
> 2- do I make a safe freeing the memory in the `delete_struct`
> function?
>
> 3- if I called `delete_struct(ptr->ptr2);` function, and tried to
> delete only ptr2, what will be the value of ptr->ptr2 ? and what
> will happens exactly when I call `delete_struct(ptr);` ?

Comment: These statements ptr->ptr1 = (my_special_struct *)maloc(sizeof(my_special_struct));
    ptr->ptr1 = pointer1; produce a memory leak.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow why?

Comment: Because the address of the allocated memory is lost.

Comment: And these statements  ptr->ptr2 = (my_special_struct *)malloc(sizeof(my_special_struct));
    ptr->ptr2 = NULL; in whole do not make sense.

Comment: When you do `ptr->ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(my_special_struct)); ptr->ptr2 = NULL;` that's like having `int x; x = 5; x = 0;` and then wonder why `x` isn't `5` anymore.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so are you saying that making `ptr->ptr2=NULL;` is exactly like `free(ptr->ptr2);`  , I do not think so.

I want to allocate a memory and give it a NULL, so in case I never assign value to it during running the code it will be NULL

Comment: @KamalEl-Saaid No it does *not* free the memory you previously allocated. Instead you *loose* the original pointer and *can't* pass it to `free`. The memory allocated by `malloc(sizeof(my_special_struct))` is lost, it's a *leak*.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow why do you think it does not make sense? and how to allocate the memory for the whole struct safely?

Comment: @KamalEl-Saaid Because again there is a memory leak. To set a pointer to NULL there is no need to allocate memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but if I did not make `ptr->ptr2 = NULL;`, then during deleting, I can not know if it has value assigned or not

Comment: You should keep the assignment to `NULL`, but not do the `malloc` call. The `malloc` Call isn't needed for the pointer itself, you don't need to allocate space for the pointer variable (that's already done by the compiler, just like any non-pointer variable).

Comment: so if I just make the `ptr->ptr2=NULL;` and when I need to assign a value to it, then I malloc it and it will work as I want?

Comment: @KamalEl-Saaid "So if I just make the ptr->ptr2=NULL; and when I need to assign a value to it, then I malloc it" Yes that's correct. But "it will work as I want?" depends on the rest of the code. At least you have prevented a memory leak.

Comment: @KamalEl-Saaid These else statements else{
          free(ptr->ptr1);
      }
  
   else{
          free(ptr->ptr2);
      } are redundent.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ah yah, as it will be NULL and we did not allocate a memory to it, then there is nothing to free, right?

Comment: @KamalEl-Saaid A null pointer does not point to a valid object. So there is nothing to free.

Answer (score -1):

On surface, thisis a question on a binary tree.

1. For ptr2, as noted by commented, it's enough to assign NULL pointer. Allocating memory will just result in lost ("leaked") memory.
2. Sample code using recursive version of delete_struct. So that function should either delete the children, or delete the current element (but not both). Also good practice is to NULL delete pointers to avoid accidental resuse
3. Calling 'free' does not change the value of the pointer, it marked the memory area that available for re-use.

alternative delete + pointer cleanup.

```
void delete_struct(struct my_special_struct ptr){
   if ( ptr != NULL ) {
       delete_struct(ptr->ptr1);
       ptr->ptr1 = NULL ;

       delete_struct(ptr->ptr2);
       ptr->ptr2 = NULL ;

       free(ptr);
   }
}
```

Comment: following the same strategy, why did not you make `ptr=NULL;` after doing `free(ptr)`

Comment: @KamalEl-Saaid Technically, you are right, good idea to NULL after free (IMHO). On a practical term, this is local variable, and delete_struct ends immediately after the 'free' so this is not contributing much to the flow/safety of the function

Comment: @dash-o I think you mean void delete_struct(struct my_special_struct *ptr){ Setting pointers to NULL of deleted objects does not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Setting those pointer to NULL reduces that change that the buggy code will attempt to de-refernce those pointers.

Comment: @dash-o They can not be dereferenced because they are data members of deleted objects. It is enough to set to NULL the pointer that points to the root node.